# how to return json response to my android app Cakephp

Tags: android, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x ... i want to return a response to my android app with som data in json ..here is my function that how i am getting a response in my cakephp web..

```
     public function phone(){
           $this->loadModel('User');

         if ($this->request->isPost()){

           $json = $this->request->data('json');
           $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        if($data){
      //here i want to send response back to mobile app  
          }
    }
```

i want to return like  this in my json response.. i mean i want to send the variable name and its value in a json response

```
       [Contact] => Array
            (
                [idContacts] => 1
                [name] => asad
                [mobileNo] => 03224999464
```

Comment: Why not using the JsonView as documented? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: @mark dont know how to use them

Comment: It is very well describe there. Sorry but after seeing you asking a lot of questions like this it really looks like you *do not want* to read but instead you want to get your work done by other providing you code you can copy and paste. If you have a problem working with well written documentation you might want to resolve that issue before continue to program because working with documentation is an essential part of programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i am guessing you can use with sample to do it as revert

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

you can also do with multidimensional array.

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: welcome @hellosheikh i am really glad to help you, please vote up my answer to make it use full to other which might be related issue in future.

Comment: If using that (IMHO wrong approach in CakePHP) you want to call $this->_stop() after you echoed the json in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The proper CakePHPish way of doing this is described here.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

The answer vom liyakat has a few downsides.

It is not sending the proper header, you do not have the .json extension in the URL (which you should have there for json IMHO), you can not use the advantages of the RequestHandler and reuse the same action for json and non json view. Also using the way described in the book it easy dead easy to server json and xml at the same time for example.